# How do i become better at css positioning, and floats?

Tags: css

I know the question is very generic, but I'm trying to become better with layouts and floats, the positioning part of css.  Are there any good resources i should look at or methods you guys recommend I can use to become better?

Comment: As with anything you want to get better at, practice. Build lots of websites. Lots and lots of them.

Comment: Focus on one browser to start. And then, just play with it. The bang-your-head-against-it-and-you'll-get-it philosophy works here I guess. Also, if you want something quick-and-not-so-dirty, use twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- w3schools.com
- http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/
- http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
- http://spyrestudios.com/css-in-depth-floats-positions/
- http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/absolute-positioning-vs-floats/

Really, just practice, mess around, and eventually you'll get it.

Or if you have a more concrete question, I'll be happy to see if I can answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Code Academy has a [section dedicated to this](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-6merh) in their HTML/CSS course.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.jsfiddle.net

Try random things and see what works.

That is how most of us learned.